# Squashing and Expanding Object in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this following requirement.

Let's assume I have Activity class

```
class Activity{
    String name;
    String activityId;
    List<String> activityIds = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...
}
```

Now, I have a list of activities (`List<Activity>`). Some activities can 
have the same name, but have different activityIds.
In this case, I want to create the same Activity object, with a null
activityId and  a list of activityIds.

I also want to do the reverse.

I have written the code. Is there a better way to do this ?

**Sample Input:**

```
Activity a1 = new Activity("ABC","Mark");
Activity a2 = new Activity("1","Boucher");
Activity a3 = new Activity("2","Portman");
Activity a4 = new Activity("3","Mark");
Activity a5 = new Activity("4","Caprio");
Activity a6 = new Activity("PQR","Portman");
List<Activity> activities = Arrays.asList(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6);
```

**Sample Output :**

```
[Activity [name=Portman, activityId=null, activityIds=[2, PQR]]
, Activity [name=Caprio, activityId=null, activityIds=[4]]
, Activity [name=Mark, activityId=null, activityIds=[ABC, 3]]
, Activity [name=Boucher, activityId=null, activityIds=[1]]
]
```

I also want to do the reverse, which will print the original list.

I have written the code .[Full code is here](https://gist.github.com/vinoct6/775cc01711e6f965433f). **Is there any better way to do it ?**

```
private static List<Activity> squashDTO(List<Activity> dtoList){    
    List<Activity> filteredActivity = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, List<Activity>> activityMap = dtoList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Activity::getName));
    activityMap.forEach(( key,value) ->{ 
        Activity a = new Activity(value.get(0).getName());
        List<String> activityIds = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Activity aa : value){           
            activityIds.add(aa.getActivityId());
        }
        a.setActivityIds(activityIds);
        filteredActivity.add(a);                
    });     
    return filteredActivity;
}
```

And expandActivity

```
private static List<Activity> expandDTO(List<Activity> dtoList){
    List<Activity> newList = new ArrayList<Activity>();
    for(Activity a : dtoList){
        for(String activityId : a.getActivityIds()){
            Activity n = new Activity(activityId,a.getName());
              newList.add(n);
         }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to group by the name of the activity and collect their ids into a list.

This is done by using the [`groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector. In this case, the downstream collector maps each activity to their id and collects them into a list. With this, we obtain a map that we need to post-process to have the list of wanted activies. As such, this is wrapped into the [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) collector that maps each entry of the map into an `Activity` with a `null` id.

(NB: the following assumes a constructor `public Activity(String activityId, String name, List<String> activityIds)` and getters for each property)

```
List<Activity> output =
    activities.stream()
              .collect(collectingAndThen(
                  groupingBy(
                    Activity::getName,
                    mapping(Activity::getActivityId, toList())
                  ),
                  m -> m.entrySet().stream()
                                   .map(e -> new Activity(null, e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                                   .collect(toList())
              ));
```

To make the reverse and reconstruct the input list, we need to flatten by the activity ids. In the following, the list is flattened by storing the name and the list of ids in a temporary `SimpleEntry` (that only serves as a tuple) and finally, all this is collected back into a list of activities.

```
List<Activity> input =
    output.stream()
          .flatMap(a -> a.getActivityIds().stream().map(l -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(l, a.getName())))
          .map(e -> new Activity(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
          .collect(toList());
```

---

Static imports used:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```